# How do I create params in a SOAP-Request in Perl using SOAP::Lite?

Tags: xml, perl, soap

How can I make the following request in perl, using SOAP::Lite?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <InsertVerbalRecording xmlns="xyz.abc.ws">
      <inVar>
        <VerbalPrefix>string</VerbalPrefix>
        <VerbalID>int</VerbalID>
        <ClientNo>int</ClientNo>
      </inVar>
    </InsertVerbalRecording>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out, it should work like this...

`my @params = SOAP::Data->name("inVar" => \SOAP::Data->value((SOAP::Data->name(VerbalPrefix => 'V'),
              SOAP::Data->name(VerbalID => $verbalId),`

After adding the params, make the call to the actual method...

`my $res = $proxy->call('InsertVerbalRecording' => @params);`

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? Where does the rest of the stuff, i.e. `InsertVerbalRecording` come from?